# Add daily status value to records ID in bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table with records for each ID at a certain date. I want the table to have the missing dates for the IDs to track daily status of a value. If there isn't any change, the value from previous day will carry on.

*The date list should be set to `CURRENT_DATE()`, so I always have current date status of value. For the example below, `2023-02-05` is the current date therefore an ID might not have any change at current date.

This is the table

| ID | First_name | Last_name | Date | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| aaa | Adam | Glen | 2023-02-02 | Green |
| aaa | Adam | Glen | 2023-02-05 | Red |
| bbb | Daniel | Blue | 2023-02-02 | Red |
| bbb | Daniel | Blue | 2023-02-04 | Green |

This is the output I want to have from the query

| ID | First_name | Last_name | Date | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| aaa | Adam | Glen | 2023-02-02 | Green |
| aaa | Adam | Glen | 2023-02-03 | Green |
| aaa | Adam | Glen | 2023-02-04 | Green |
| aaa | Adam | Glen | 2023-02-05 | Red |
| bbb | Daniel | Blue | 2023-02-02 | Red |
| bbb | Daniel | Blue | 2023-02-03 | Red |
| bbb | Daniel | Blue | 2023-02-04 | Green |
| bbb | Daniel | Blue | 2023-02-05 | Green |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little bit verbose but you might consider below approach.

```sql
SELECT * EXCEPT(Min_date, Value),
       COALESCE(Value,LAST_VALUE(Value IGNORE NULLS) OVER w) AS Value 
  FROM (
    SELECT ID, First_name, Last_name, MIN(Date) Min_date FROM sample_table GROUP BY 1, 2, 3
  ), UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(Min_date, '2023-02-05')) Date
  LEFT JOIN sample_table USING (ID, First_name, Last_name, Date)
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Date);
```

**Query results**

[image]

- you can replace `2023-02-05` in `GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(Min_date, '2023-02-05')` with `CURRENT_DATE`